# My hand is numb

Tags: negation, subject-verb-agreement

> My hand is numb.
>
> My hand feel numb.
>
> I can't feel my hand.

I pressed my hand last night. My hand is numb/feel numb/can't feel my hand.

Which ones is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are right as written:

> My hand is numb.
>   I can't feel my hand.

The other one should be:

> My hand feels numb.

All good sentences!

Answer (score 3):

As a healthcare provider, I have encountered almost all the expressions to express that there is numbness in some part of body.

The fact is, the word *numb* is an *[adjective](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/numb_1)* and thus can be used the way you have used.

> My [hand is numb](http://ottawacitizen.com/news/local-news/case-closed-but-woman-pleads-she-deserves-full-income-benefit-for-workplace-injury) 
>  My [hand feels numb](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-nottinghamshire-10723644)

And since *numbness* is [loss of feeling](http://diabetes.niddk.nih.gov/dm/pubs/neuropathies/), in the context of telling a *medical symptom*, you can even say...

> I cannot feel my hand.